# MySQL on excel key not present in the dictionary

Tags: mysql, excel

I have installed MySQL on Excel to use some data that I created, every time I try to connect it gives me this error: the given key was not present in the dictionary.

I can connect with no problem through datagrip, python and the Mysql Workbench.
This same problem appears in my other pcs (that use windows 10 and 11)

What can I do?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5T7y.png)

Comment: you have not installed mysql on excel, you have installed a tool that connects excel to a mysql server. Do you have a mysql server to connect to?

Comment: Yes I have a mysql server functioning, I already did some queries with python and datagrip. So how can I install mysql to excel?